# How to use NPAPI (Silverlight for Netflix etc) in Chrome after September 2015 (version 45 update)

Tags: google-chrome, browser, silverlight, netflix, npapi

Come September Google want npapi to RIP - https://www.chromium.org/developers/npapi-deprecation

What is a good strategy to prevent Chrome from updating beyond version 44 or a similar workaround?

Many sites/web-apps are likely to lag behind and still require Silverlight, or similar, so I would like to buy myself more time... open to all suggestions to avoid reverting to another browser.

Comment: Note that Netflix no longer requires Silverlight - they now offer an HTML5 video player: https://gigaom.com/2014/11/26/netflix-silverlight-chrome/

Comment: @KCD - This isn't worth an answer.  Google offers an Chrome add-on called **Chrome Legacy Browser Support (Chrome LBS)** for exactly this purpose.

Comment: @Ramhound sounds like the only answer

Answer (score 0):

The only strategy I've seen is to use browsers that support NPAPI.

I'm a developer, but not a plug-in developer.  I can only assume that the newer PPAPI, and the older NPAPI, are mismatched enough that no one has created a simple adapter.

Comment: There are no plans to support PPAPI in Firefox